# UIPickerView not registering the correct last row. Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uipicker

I have a 2 UIPickerView's, one called dayPicker where you have an option between 1-12 and durationPicker where you have the options of days, weeks, months and years.

The code for this is below:

```
class AddNewViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var dayPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var durationPicker: UIPickerView!
    var durationDay: Double?
    var durationType: String?

    var durationPickerDataSource = ["Day(s)","Week(s)","Month(s)","Year(s)"];
     var dayPickerDataSource = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"];


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(dayPickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == durationPicker {
        return durationPickerDataSource.count;
    }
    else {
        return dayPickerDataSource.count;
    }
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == durationPicker{
        durationType = durationPickerDataSource[row]
        print("")
        print("")
        print("\(row): type == \(durationType)")
        print("\(row)")
        print("")
        print("")

        return durationType
    }
    else {
        durationDay = Double(dayPickerDataSource[row])
        return dayPickerDataSource[row]
    }
}
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.durationPicker.dataSource = self;
        self.durationPicker.delegate = self;
        self.dayPicker.dataSource = self;
        self.dayPicker.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

when I select the rows in the simulator it prints all of the rows correctly apart from the last one where it prints "Week(s)".

I have the following constraints on the pickers:

dayPicker:

[image: daypicker]

durationPicker:

[image: durationPicker]

Comment: does the `titleForRow` function print the correct values ? And can you show us your selection code as well ?

Comment: hi @the_critic, the titleForRow doesn't show the correct values, for the last column it shows row 1 when it should be 3. What selection code?

Comment: never mind... What's the output you get in `titleForRow` ? Are the first values correct ? Can you modify your `print("type == \(durationType)")`  to `print("\(row): type == \(durationType)")` and tell me what the output is ?

Comment: sure. I get - 0: type == Optional("Day(s)"), 1: type == Optional("Week(s)"), 2: type == Optional("Month(s)"), 1: type == Optional("Week(s)").
it seems to the the titleForRow which is been detected as wrong

Comment: Yes, definitely strange... Can you post more of your code please ?

Comment: Also (most probably not the issue here, but still a good practice) make sure you call `super.viewDidLoad()` first in your `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: My assumption is that you have multiple picker views in your view controller, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes i have 2, 1 called dayPicker and 1 durationPicker. Ill update my code now.

Comment: @the_critic its now updated above

Comment: Quite frankly, now I don't really see any issues after your update ... Does the daypicker display it's data correctly ?

Comment: No that one doesn't work either. it shows 10 instead of 12.

Comment: @the_critic when the last row is selected (12) and it shows 10 and then you go backwards and select 11 it shows 9, its like its misusing one rather than rechecking the titleForRow

Comment: are you modifying your data sources by any chance ?

Comment: I tested your code, it works fine for me. You'd need to post more of your code for me to inspect what's wrong.

Comment: @the_critic no, the only time i refer to the data sources is when i assign the data source row to a variable. e.g. durationDay = Double(dayPickerDataSource[row])

Comment: Take a look at the screenshot I posted, the pickers display the data correctly, you must be doing something else in your view controller that messes with the data. I made no modifications to the code whatsoever...

Comment: by modifying the data sources do you mean the array of strings which are displayed?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: I have commented everything out within my view controller and still get the problem. I have another picker view in another ViewController which was created programatically rather than a static array and i still have the problem. Does this mean its related to my xCode settings?

Comment: definitely not an XCode issue... The only way I can confirm that you have the correct code is if you post it in its entirety so that I can reproduce your issues.

Comment: you can also try to plug your code into a clean project and confirm that it works there (I did that and apparently the code you posted works for me...). It takes a a minute or two to do that...

Comment: how do i plug the code into a clean project? I tried to clean it using command-options-shit-K but that didnt resolve the issue

Comment: By "plugging into a clean project" I meant creating a new project...

Comment: Hi @the_critic, i created a new project and it worked. When i started editing my storyboard it stopped working again. I think its to do with the height of the picker! when the height is 500 for example it works, when its 50 it doesn't.

Comment: I changed the picker's height to 50 and it still displays correctly...

Comment: hmm thats really weird, when i have a large height (>200) it works as expected. What other constraints do you have on the picker?

Comment: If you look at the screenshot I posted in my answer, the pickers are pinned to the edges (left,top,right) and additionally I added a height constraint with the value of 50.

Comment: Ok ill take a look when it loads. Cant see anything yet.

Comment: hmm this is really odd. Do you have auto layout selected? I'm thinking it is a constraint issue somehow as i only have the code which i posted above

Comment: Yes it's all auto-layout

Comment: I have updated my question with the constraints i have which don't work. Do they work for you?

Comment: yes they do work for me

Comment: Hmm odd. would it be possible for me to send you my project or vice versa?

Comment: sure, here you go: https://bitbucket.org/melkhaiat/so-uipickerview

Comment: may be a stupid question but how do i run the project on the simulator rather than the default ios device?

Comment: just click on the button that says "Generic iOS Device" (right next to the target) and choose the simulator

Comment: top left corner right next to the "Run" button

Comment: Thanks, i needed to specify the deployment device before i could select a simulator.

Comment: Your code has a function which has 'didSelectRow' which mine didn't. Once i add that function to my code it works as expected! Thanks for all your help

Comment: seriously ? I never imagined this would be the issue tbh... I still can't believe this is the problem, but if it solves yours, congrats!

Comment: Yeah! I can't believe it was that either. Learn something new everyday. If you add your code from your project to your answer ill accept it :)

Comment: Glad it worked out in the end. Updated my answer. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied your code, everything seems to work fine. My only guess is that you are modifying your data sources and therefore the picker delegate returns the wrong information.

I tested your code (without modifications), the pickers display the correct values...

### EDIT:

From the comment section it seems the problem lies in not having specified the `UIPickerView`'s `didSelectRow` method, adding it seemingly solved the OP's problem (can't elaborate on the "why" though...):

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView == self.dayPicker{
      print("picked \(dayPickerDataSource[row])")
    }else {
      print("picked \(durationPickerDataSource[row])")
    }

  }
```